# Exporting data set from excel to SPSS: Continuous variables falsely coded as nominal

Tags: excel, transform, numeric, spss

I am importing a excel data set into SPSS. Unfortunately, a lot of numerical variables are seen as nominal.
Does anyone understand how I need to change the variables in excel so that they are imported correctly?

Thanks for your help and best regards,
Lukas

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause for this is when you have many empty cells in a numeric column in excel, SPSS might think this is a string column by default, even though there are some numbers in the column, all due to this default sub-command:

```
  /DATATYPEMIN PERCENTAGE=95.0
```

If this indeed is the problem, all you have to do is change to

```
  /DATATYPEMIN PERCENTAGE=100
```